# Setting up beat.hostname in Metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, metricbeat

I am super new to these concepts, I apologize if this is a silly thing. I am trying to visualize Metricbeat data on Grafana with Elasticsearch data source, all running locally, but unable to find where "beat.hostname" is added in Metricbeat config.

I have the latest version of both Grafana and Metricbeat and am following this [article](https://fabianlee.org/2017/01/15/grafana-connecting-to-an-elasticsearch-datasource/). In the "Create Dashboard" section, the author mentions that he used "beat.hostname=grafana" as the host name when installing Metricbeat. He then used it on the query editor field to pull out the data on Grafana dashboard.

But where do we set this up? I looked the two YAML files in the Metricbeat folder but there is nothing describing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just refer the 'Name' variable in your metricbeat.yml

```
# ================================== General ===================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
name: "jeremy-laptop"

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
tags: ["laptop", "ubuntu"]
```

And you will find this value as "*host.name*" and be able to filter on it.

[image]

I'm not really a user of Grafana, so this part will be on your side